# "to" vs. "until"

Tags: grammar

If I wanted to say that something lasts all night and ends in the morning, I could use, "until morning." But what about "to morning?" Would that also be correct? I'm not sure because "to" here is referring to a time and not a place.

Answer (score 3):

"Until morning" is the better choice.  You may see "to" used with a specific time ("the meeting is from 2 to 4"), but it's not usually used with fuzzier end-points like "morning".

Comment: You said "usually." Can you think of some counter-examples?

Comment: I don't know if this is quite the same, but consider (referring to a movie) "I stayed to the end of the credits".  I would say "through", but I know I've heard "to".

Comment: The meeting has been deferred until / to June.

Answer (score -1):

Using "to" with time is simply incorrect usage, albeit common. Until or 'til is correct. Every time I see "open 9 to midnight" or somesuch I cringe.

Comment: -1 for lack of support or evidence.

Comment: Damian: Welcome to English Language and Usage Stack Exchange. I don't want to discourage you from answering, and I hope you do continue to contribute answers. I personally think your answer would be better if you provided some support for it.

Answer (score -2):

"To" just isn't used to refer to time, so It wouldn't be correct.

["To"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/to) actually has no usage which refers to time. In all its usages, it refers to intention, place, but not time.

Notice we only say :"till morning", or "until 12.00" or "continues until morning", but never "to".

Comment: While I agree that "until" is the right word to use here, I offer the counter-example "9 to 5".

Comment: 9 to 5 is still incorrect. It's actually 9 til 5, but due to its affinity with numbers i.e. Find squares of numbers from 5 to 9; but it doesn't mean its correct.

Comment: I also hear/use "We're open from 7am to 11pm", "It rained from dawn to dusk", and so forth.

Comment: -1: There's also this from [your link](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/to#Preposition): (_time_) Preceding
_ten to ten = 9:50; We're going to leave at ten to (the hour)_.

Comment: I'd have to agree with Ham and Bacon. Although you do find "to" used in these constructions, it is in fact a reduction of "'til". Consider: "We worked til nine versus" the (awkward/incorrect to me) "We worked to nine". If you like "to nine", how do you like "What time did they work to?" My guess is most native English speakers would find the question form objectionable with "to", but fine with "til".

Comment: "What time did they work (to|until)?" is bad with either word, for dangling a preposition.  If you reorganize the sentence to "(To|Until) when did they work?" it sounds much less awkward with either word.

Comment: [Dictionary.com definition of *to:*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/to) prep. 5. used for expressing a point of limit in time) before; until:
*to this day; It is ten minutes to six. We work from nine to five.*